# "PostMessage" from a working thread to send a message to the main GUI thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, message-queue

i have created a thread and now i want to send message(to do a particular event) from the thread to the main GUI thread, so that th GUI thread can execute my message.can any one tell me how to do this in iphone(Objective C)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  //This will call selected method on main thread and you can do what ever you want to do in your selected method.

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(yourmethod) withObject:yourobject waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Hope, this will help you..

Answer (score 1):

You can use GCD and blocks

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // UI code to run on main thread
});
```